# Discord.py | Get guild emojis

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a p/guild-info command and I need to get all the emojis in the context guild. But if I enter **str(ctx. message.guild.emojis)** then will return the error *" Command raised an exception: HttpException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In embed.fields.5. value: Must be 1024 or fewer in length."*
; if I enter **emojis = get(ctx. message.guild.emojies)** it will give out one random emoji

How do I get all the guild emojis correctly?

Comment: Could we have a larger snippet of code? you are working with? it looks like you are sending a bad request later in the code, but I am not sure. Include the imports and around 10-50 lines of code if possible. Sometimes more or less is necessary

Comment: Also this a bit difficult to read try using code block by surrounding the cod in  three tic ` marks ```code```